# Problemas centrando vídeos

Tags: html, css

Buenas, estoy intentado poner los vídeos en el centro de la página sin alterar ningún otro elemento. He probado usando float: center, align: center y margin: 0 auto y ninguno de estos funciona. Adjunto foto de como está actualmente y código.
**FOTO:**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CÓDIGO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
     if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
      $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
     } else {
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
     }
    });
    $("#news").mouseover(function(){
     $("#news").css("background-color", "#800000");
     $("#a").css("color",black);
    });
    
    $("#conciertos").mouseover(function(){
     $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });   
    
    $("#songs").mouseover(function(){
     $("#songs").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });    

    $("#lyrics").mouseover(function(){
     $("#lyrics").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $("#store").mouseover(function(){
     $("#store").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".listaArriba").css("background-color","#B22222");
     $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    $("#video1").hide();
    $("#video2").hide();
    $("#video3").hide();
    $("#video4").hide();
    $("#foto1").click(function(){
     $("#video2").hide();
     $("#video3").hide();
     $("#video4").hide();
     $("#video1").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
    $("#foto2").click(function(){
     $("#video1").hide();
     $("#video3").hide();
     $("#video4").hide();
     $("#video2").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
    $("#foto3").click(function(){
     $("#video2").hide();
     $("#video1").hide();
     $("#video4").hide();
     $("#video3").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
    $("#foto4").click(function(){
     $("#video2").hide();
     $("#video3").hide();
     $("#video1").hide();
     $("#video4").fadeIn(1000);
    });
   });
```

```css
.headerEnd{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:110px;
   }
   #fotoEndi{
    margin-left: 100px;
   }
   
   @font-face{
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    src: url("GameofBrush.ttf");
   }
   a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    
   }
   a:visited{
    color: #000000;
   }
   
   #nombreEndi{
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    color: #8B0000; 
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    font-size:40px;
   }
   
   .header{
    height:100px; width:100%;
    text-align:center;
   }
   
   .menu{
    height: 37px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #B22222; 
    color:#333; 
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0)
   }
   .wrapper{ height:2000px; 
      width:100%; 
      padding-top:20px
   }
   .menu-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
   }
   ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
   }
   
   body{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    margin: 0;
   }

   #menu li{
    background: #DCDCDC;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   .listaArriba{
    color:  #000000;
    width: 150px;
   }
   
   #titulua{
        background-color:#000;
     text-align:center;
     margin-left: 300px;
     margin-top: 7px;
   }
   
   .seccion1{
    background-color: white;
    height:749px;
    width: 1350px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
   }
   #footer{
    margin-top:0px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   #soundcloud{
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top: 3px;
   }
   .navigationFoot{
    text-align: right;
   }
   #creditos{
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
   }
   a{
    color:black;
   }
   #o{
    margin-left: 250px;
    float: top;
   }
   
   .videos{
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
   }
   
   #oneMoreShot{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
   }
   
   #oMSmin{
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    border: 4px solid;
   }
   
   #texto{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top:90px;
    margin-left:200px;
   }
   
   h1{
    margin-left: 100px;
   }
   
   #sK{
    border: 4px solid white;
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    
   }
   
   #foto1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:240px;
    
   }
   
   #foto2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 250px;
   }
   
   #foto3{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 230px;

   }

   #foto4{
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 250px;
   }
   
   #texto1{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:100px;
    color: #FFFAF0;
   }
   
   #texto2{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left: 150px;
   }
   .video{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <iframe id="video1" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xErYAGUgCjQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe id="video2" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SQVNwyQrbUM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe id="video3" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/80n-HVUI-UM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe id="video4" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VGZb2gt1r4c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
  <header class="headerEnd">
   <div class = "cabecera">
    <ul id = "lista1">
     <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
     <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
  <header class = "header">
   <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <nav class="top-menu">
     <ul class = "navigation">
      <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
    
    <div class="videos" style="overflow:scroll;">
      <div id="foto1">
       <img  id="oMSmin" src="../CaratulasAlbum/oneMoreShotmin.jpg"/> <h1 id="texto"><strong>ONE MORE SHOT</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="foto2">
       <h1 id="texto1"><strong>STOLEN KISS</strong></h1> <img id="sK" align="right" src="../CaratulasAlbum/stolenKissmin.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div id="foto3">
       <img  id="oMSmin" src="../CaratulasAlbum/wandermin.jpg"/> <h1 id="texto2"><strong>WANDERING AIMLESSLY</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="foto4">
       <h1 id="texto1"><strong>THE NIGHT HEARS</strong></h1> <img id="sK" align="right" src="../CaratulasAlbum/theNightmin.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="footer">
     <ul class = "navigationFoot">
      <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
     </ul>

   </div>
  </header>
```

PD: Si se ejecuta el código no aparecerá el reproductor hasta que se haga click en algún título.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con `position: fixed` y estableciendo el `top` y `left` relativo:

```
.video{
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 157px);
  left: calc(50% - 280px);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
     if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
      $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
     } else {
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
     }
    });
    $("#news").mouseover(function(){
     $("#news").css("background-color", "#800000");
     $("#a").css("color",black);
    });
    
    $("#conciertos").mouseover(function(){
     $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });   
    
    $("#songs").mouseover(function(){
     $("#songs").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });    

    $("#lyrics").mouseover(function(){
     $("#lyrics").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $("#store").mouseover(function(){
     $("#store").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".listaArriba").css("background-color","#B22222");
     $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    $("#video1").hide();
    $("#video2").hide();
    $("#video3").hide();
    $("#video4").hide();
    $("#foto1").click(function(){
     $("#video2").hide();
     $("#video3").hide();
     $("#video4").hide();
     $("#video1").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
    $("#foto2").click(function(){
     $("#video1").hide();
     $("#video3").hide();
     $("#video4").hide();
     $("#video2").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
    $("#foto3").click(function(){
     $("#video2").hide();
     $("#video1").hide();
     $("#video4").hide();
     $("#video3").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
    $("#foto4").click(function(){
     $("#video2").hide();
     $("#video3").hide();
     $("#video1").hide();
     $("#video4").fadeIn(1000);
    });
   });
```

```css
.headerEnd{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:110px;
   }
   #fotoEndi{
    margin-left: 100px;
   }
   
   @font-face{
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    src: url("GameofBrush.ttf");
   }
   a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    
   }
   a:visited{
    color: #000000;
   }
   
   #nombreEndi{
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    color: #8B0000; 
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    font-size:40px;
   }
   
   .header{
    height:100px; width:100%;
    text-align:center;
   }
   
   .menu{
    height: 37px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #B22222; 
    color:#333; 
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0)
   }
   .wrapper{ height:2000px; 
      width:100%; 
      padding-top:20px
   }
   .menu-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
   }
   ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
   }
   
   body{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    margin: 0;
   }

   #menu li{
    background: #DCDCDC;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   .listaArriba{
    color:  #000000;
    width: 150px;
   }
   
   #titulua{
        background-color:#000;
     text-align:center;
     margin-left: 300px;
     margin-top: 7px;
   }
   
   .seccion1{
    background-color: white;
    height:749px;
    width: 1350px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
   }
   #footer{
    margin-top:0px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   #soundcloud{
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top: 3px;
   }
   .navigationFoot{
    text-align: right;
   }
   #creditos{
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
   }
   a{
    color:black;
   }
   #o{
    margin-left: 250px;
    float: top;
   }
   
   .videos{
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
   }
   
   #oneMoreShot{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
   }
   
   #oMSmin{
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    border: 4px solid;
   }
   
   #texto{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top:90px;
    margin-left:200px;
   }
   
   h1{
    margin-left: 100px;
   }
   
   #sK{
    border: 4px solid white;
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    
   }
   
   #foto1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:240px;
    
   }
   
   #foto2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 250px;
   }
   
   #foto3{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 230px;

   }

   #foto4{
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 250px;
   }
   
   #texto1{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:100px;
    color: #FFFAF0;
   }
   
   #texto2{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left: 150px;
   }
   .video{
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(50% - 157px);
    left: calc(50% - 280px);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <iframe id="video1" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xErYAGUgCjQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe id="video2" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SQVNwyQrbUM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe id="video3" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/80n-HVUI-UM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe id="video4" class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VGZb2gt1r4c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
  <header class="headerEnd">
   <div class = "cabecera">
    <ul id = "lista1">
     <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
     <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
  <header class = "header">
   <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <nav class="top-menu">
     <ul class = "navigation">
      <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
    
    <div class="videos" style="overflow:scroll;">
      <div id="foto1">
       <img  id="oMSmin" src="../CaratulasAlbum/oneMoreShotmin.jpg"/> <h1 id="texto"><strong>ONE MORE SHOT</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="foto2">
       <h1 id="texto1"><strong>STOLEN KISS</strong></h1> <img id="sK" align="right" src="../CaratulasAlbum/stolenKissmin.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div id="foto3">
       <img  id="oMSmin" src="../CaratulasAlbum/wandermin.jpg"/> <h1 id="texto2"><strong>WANDERING AIMLESSLY</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="foto4">
       <h1 id="texto1"><strong>THE NIGHT HEARS</strong></h1> <img id="sK" align="right" src="../CaratulasAlbum/theNightmin.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="footer">
     <ul class = "navigationFoot">
      <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
     </ul>

   </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Se ha centrado el vídeo, pero solo horizontalmente. Lo que necesito es que esté en el centro de la pantalla.

Comment: Perdona me faltaba el `calc` en la propiedad `top`

Comment: Ahora si funciona, gracias

Comment: Buena respuesta. Si en lugar de usar el `calc` usases `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`, la misma propiedad centraría todos los vídeos incluso si son de diferentes tamaños (o si el tamaño cambia en el futuro).